# How to render images with React JS using map or loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my js file, which contains my images.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Stopka.css';

class Stopka extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <footer className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <h4>Some text</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <img src={require("./icons/name1.png")} alt="" className="img-responsive" />
                        <img src={require("./icons/name2.png")} alt="" className="img-responsive" />
                        <img src={require("./icons/name3.png")} alt="" className="img-responsive" />
                        <img src={require("./icons/name4.png")} alt="" className="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Stopka;
```

And file which render this.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Stopka from './Stopka';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';



ReactDOM.render(<Stopka />, document.getElementById('stopka'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

For now my images is not rendering in much optimize mode, cuz if i want to add 20 or even more it'll be so much pain. I want to render it with loop or map function. Tried some but it doesn't work. Can you explain how can I do it?

This is what i tried.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Stopka.css';

class Stopka extends Component {
    render() {
        let names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.props.level; i++) {
            names.push(<image src={require("./icons/"+names+".png")} alt="" className="img-responsive" key={i} />  );
        }
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <footer className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <h4>Some text</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        {names}
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Stopka;
```

Another try

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Stopka.css';

class Stopka extends Component {
    render() {
        let names = ['wood', 'sun'];

        let images = names.map(name => {

            <img
            src = {require("./icons/{name}.png")}
            alt = ""
                className="img-responsive" />
        });
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <footer className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <h4>some text</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        { images }

                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Stopka;
```

But this get error "Module not found: Can't resolve './icons/{name}.png' "

Comment: Can you show what you did already that didn't work? Basically having them all as an array and mapping through them is all you need

Comment: Post edited, I added what i done.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the js [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function combined with [ES 6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
class Stopka extends Component {
    render() {

        const array = ["wood", "lake", "sun", "moon", "sea"];

        const images = array.map(image => {
           return <img key={image} src={require(`./icons/${image}.png`)} className="img-responsive" />
        });

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <footer className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <h4>Some text</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                       { images }
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Stopka;
```

Comment: Unexpected token, expected ; on line 8 near =>
Btw. from what I see, it render all images from folder icons?

Comment: The names "name1, name2,... name100" was just for example. How can i do it with diffrent names? Like wood, lake, sun, moon, sea? Create array and put it in src like you did but without "name" before ${image} ?

Comment: @Brunhilda no worres!

Comment: Is there a way to populate an array dynamically so it has all the filenames from a specific folder including file extension?

Comment: @Dobrobobr perhaps this could work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801606/list-folder-contents-with-reactjs

Comment: @pau1fitzgerald Managed to do it by combining bits of code from different answers `function importAll(r) {
        return r.keys().map(r);
      }
      
      const images = importAll(require.context('static/UniLogo/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
      const imageArray = images.map(function(image) {
        return <img key={image} src={image} />;
      }); `

Answer (score 3):

For others who had the same problem as me. This is working example as well.
In my opinion with key index is better, cuz it not produce errors in console.
Great for bigger projects.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Stopka.css';

class Stopka extends Component {
    render() {
        let names = ['wood', 'sun', 'moon', 'sea'].map( (name, index) => {
            return <img key={index} className="img-responsive" alt="" src={require(`./icons/${name}.png`)} />
        } );
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <footer className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <h4>some text</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        { names }

                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Stopka;
```

Thanks to Paul Fitzgerald for the guide.

Comment: @brunhila I updated my answer to also include a key. I used the image though, you should check out this article as to why not to use the `index` as the key https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much.