# Read folders and files of Zip file using jszip

Tags: javascript, jszip

I am using jszip to read the zip file which has multiple folders and each folder contain multiple files and images. How to read the zip file and differentiate files between different folders ?

Comment: By `path/in/folders/to/file.txt`?

Comment: @Justinas is it possible to read zip file from a directory using jszip in react?

Comment: Ne, because it's zip library, not directory browser. Use other libs together with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List folder contents with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801606/list-folder-contents-with-reactjs)