# Get a list of files in a react web application

Tags: reactjs

I have a directory full of text files that I need to read in my react web app

```
-resources
|-file1.txt
|-file2.txt
|-file3.txt
```

I would like to store this `resources` directory somewhere in the app such that the contents of `resources` can be listed, and individual files can be iterated over on a line-by-line basis.

currently, I'm stuck on listing the files. I'm storing them like this

```
-node_modules
-public
|-resources
||-file1.txt
||-...
-src
```

But I really don't care where the `resources` directory is located. I tried using `list-react-files` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801606/list-folder-contents-with-reactjs), but got `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'`.

for further context, I was thinking the code to scan for files would be in in `App.js`, such that the scanned files could be used to populate certain components.

```
import React from "react"
import './App.css';
...


function App() {

  //searching for files
  var files = [...];

  return(
    //create components which can list and work with the files
    ...
  );
}

export default App;
```

So, to summarize the question, how can I list files in reactJS?

p.s.:

- this project was made with `create-react-app`
- part of the point is that it should be easy to add new files to this directory, but I see no reason this process has to be "dynamic"

Comment: Hey! Because React runs on the browser it can't access the file system. You can provide any file you want by placing them in the public folder, just as you were doing before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List folder contents with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801606/list-folder-contents-with-reactjs)

Comment: But I believe you can't list files in the browser, only use the ones provided by your server (through the public folder in your source code) by knowing its path. I've spent a bit of time searching the web and couldn't find anything

Comment: @AffaqAslam that relates to a server side rendered app, meaning it has access to the filesystem at build time. In this case we're talking about accessing the filesystem in the browser (client), which is not possible :(

Comment: @AffaqAslam, It is similar to my question, but does not answer it. All the solutions (one of which is referenced in this question) are non-functional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may concern, I spent more time than I should have working on this. I highly recommend converting everything to JSON files and importing them. If you want to be able to scan for JSON files, make a JSON file that includes the names of all your files, then import that and use that for scanning. Doing things dynamically is a bare.

If you don't reformat, you'll likely need to use `Fetch`, which is asynchronous, which opens up a whole can of worms if you're using a framework like `React`.

If you're just importing json files, it's super easy:

```
import files from './resources/index.json';
```

where `index.json` looks like

```
{
    "files":[
        "file1.json",
        "file2.json"
    ]
}
```

if you need to import the files more dynamically (not at the very beginning) you can use this:

```
var data = require('./resources/'+filename)
```

this will allow you to scan through your files using the `index.json` file, and load them dynamically as needed.

Comment: So as I said in my answer, a much easier approach is to move the data to JSON. ;)

Comment: yyyyyeah. It was a tough time for sure.

Comment: It's honestly really frustrating. You would think this type of functionality would be easy in any modern programming language/framework. (Or, at least not near impossible)

Comment: A 'workaroud' some people do is to use markdown files (which are well supported). You put your data in the 'frontmatter' of the markdown. Other people put the data somewhere (json or a database) pull it out and use it - but they're producing static pages (e.g. NextJS) so it's still very fast. There are a million ways to do everything.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, because I feel like it's the most helpful for people who need help, but show some love to @Dave 's answer

Answer (score 1):

When people are using your react page, it is "running" on their computer and the software does not have access to all the files and data you'd like to use.

You will need to do this at "build time" when your service is being packaged up, or "on the server".

When you are building your react app, you can hook into processes that can find files and perform operations on them. Gatsby might be your best bet. Look at how people add "markup" files to their projects, built a menu from them and then render them as blog articles. NextJS, Vite, and other frameworks and tools will work, you may just need to learn a bit more.

The other approach, to do this "on the server" means when you are running code on the server you can do almost anything you like. So, your react app would make a call (e.g. rest request) to the server (e.g. NodeJS), and the code running on the server can use `fs` and other APIs to accomplish what you'd like.

From what you describe, doing this as part of your build step is probably the best route. A much easier route is to move this data into a JSON file and/or a database and not crawl the file system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure how involved this process is, would it be a big ask to ask for some sample code of what this might look like?

Comment: Look at ViteJS and some plugins for it like https://github.com/hisland/vite-plugin-dir-list and https://github.com/hmsk/vite-plugin-markdown. You'd write a plugin like the 'markdown' plugin to process your text files when your app builds. (Or if you just want to get things working, move your files to somewhere on a server and use nodejs to list and process them inside a rest api.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a client side rendering app and not server side (node app). Resources folder you trying to list is residing in server and react app (javascript) running on browser can't access it directly.