# How to output a list of file names in React Native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, filesystems

I have been trying to figure out how to get a list of the image file names I have in my assets folder in my React Native project in Expo. I have tried a number of things like `react-native-fs` but it would say `Your javascript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist fs`. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53537668/4052363) but it's not compatible with React Native. Is there truly any way to simply output the file names from a directory for React Native? Any help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

use expo-module

```
$ expo install expo-file-system
```

Example for get file information

```
info = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(path);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I keep getting an error no matter what I've tried with .getInfoAsync() or .readDirectoryAsync(). Here is what I've tried:


`const testFunc = async () => {
        let info = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(
            FileSystem.documentDirectory + '/assets/dispensary/',
        )
        console.log(info)
    }`

and I keep getting errors like: `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Directory 'file:///var/mobile/ yadda yadda`