# How do i get the names of a files in a folder in React js

Tags: reactjs, file, filereader, file-read

I need to get a list of file names in a folder. The react project was created using vite.
The needed file dir is src/data/(the json files which i need the name of).

I know that there is fs and list-react-files but they do not work.

Comment: What do you mean fs and list-react-files do not work? Of course they work if you use it correctly. Can you elaborate how you used them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801606/list-folder-contents-with-reactjs
this post is similar to my issue also could you elaborate how to use fs then please?