# How can I render images in a loop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a card with a title, description and an image.

My file structure looks like:

```
src
 -components
 -images
 -section
   -Featured.js
```

In a config.js file I have:

```
module.exports = {

  featuredSection: [
    {
      name: 'beer-image-1',
      title: 'Mango Cart',
      description:
        'A light Wheat Ale bursting with lots of 
         fresh mango flavor and aroma, finishing 
         crisp and refreshing.',
    },
  ],
};
```

In my `Featured.js` component file I have tried:

```
const Featured = () => {
...

// Get array of all names in config file
const featuredNames = featuredSection.map((beer) => beer.name); // --> ['beer-image-1']

// Return an image for each name in `featuredNames` array
const images = featuredNames.map((image) => {
  return (
    <img
      key={image}
      src={require(`../images/${image}.jpg`)}
      alt='Beer picture'
    />
  );
});


  // Return title, desc., and image
  const card = featuredSection.map((image, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <h1>{image.title}</h1>
        <p>{image.description}</p>
        {images}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <>{card && card}</>;
}
```

This returns the title, and description but the image is not loading and only shows the alt text.

I've been trying to make use of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713362/how-to-render-images-with-react-js-using-map-or-loop/45713493) examples but it always results in the alt text showing up.

Comment: It's probably an issue with the import URL.

Comment: try to apply style to `img` tag such as giving it a `width` and `height`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you move your `images` folder to `public` folder? If you can the below code should work

```
<img
  key={image}
  src={`./images/${image}.jpg`}
  alt='Beer picture'
/>
```

If you cannot move the `images` folder try below. Use the default property of `require`. Its should have the image src.

```
const images = featuredNames.map((image) => {

  const img = require(`../images/${image}.jpg`).default;

  return (
    <img
      key={image}
      src={img}
      alt='Beer picture'
    />
  );
});
```

Comment: Using the `.default` worked! What exactly did that change?

Comment: @agw2021 require returns an object, if you look at the img src in console you will see something like `<img src=[Object object]... />`  The actual src will be in `default` property.  Please see [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9721) also

Answer (score 1):

I think in the img JSX, the src attribute does not need to add require(). It simply would check for your directory structure based on your relative path.

```
return (
  <img
    key={image}
    src={`../images/${image}.jpg`}
    alt='Beer picture'
  />
);
```

Also, I think it can be map the featuredSection directly to get the image path. I admit that it would be convenient if your item's name is same as your image's name. it would like:

```
const card = featuredSection.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      <h1>{item.title}</h1>
      <p>{item.description}</p>
      <img
        src={`../images/${item.name}.jpg`}
        alt='Beer picture'
      />
    </div>
  );
});
```